# Why can't call toHexString method from Byte since Scala2.9.0?

Tags: scala, implicit, implicit-conversion

Scala2.8.1

```
scala> val a:Byte = 1
a: Byte = 1

scala> a.toHexString

res0: String = 1
```

but Scala2.9.0

```
scala> val a:Byte = 1
a: Byte = 1

scala> a.toHexString
<console>:9: error: value toHexString is not a member of Byte
       a.toHexString
         ^
```

Why can't call toHexString method from Byte since Scala2.9.0 ?

Answer (score 3):

**Scala 2.9.0**

If the method `toHexString` is not defined inside `Byte` the compiler tries to search for an implicit conversion to a type with the method `toHexString` but this time it has no luck and that is the reason for the compile error. Actually IMHO `RichByte` should define a `toHexString` method (`RichInt` and `RichLong` have it).

**Scala 2.8.1**

I started Scala with `scala -Xprint:jvm` to see what the compiler has done:

```
scala> b.toHexString

// ... cutted the unimportant parts

scala.this.Predef.intWrapper(scala.this.Predef.byte2int(line4$object$$iw$$iw.b())).toHexString();

// ... cutted the unimportant parts
```

As we can see the first the implicit conversion `byte2int` applies, and after that the implicit conversion `intWrapper` applies and returns an instance of `RichInt` where the method `toHexString` is defined.

But currently I don't know why these two implicit conversions are chained, because actually Scala does not allow chaining of implicit conversions... Anyone can light this up?

Comment: It probably has been filed and fixed in 2.9 which is why it doesn't work anymore. Or am I wrong?